# nagios check_http does not produce right answer for some ssl sites

Tags: ssl, nagios

nagios check produces below eror some of web sites (not all) for example google. what others parameters is necessary to work it?

```
$ check_http -w 5 -c 10 --ssl -H www.google.com -v

CRITICAL - Cannot make SSL connection
140484382566048:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:749:

GET / HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: check_http/v1.4.15 (nagios-plugins 1.4.15)

Connection: close

Host: www.google.com

HTTP CRITICAL - Error on receive
```

Comment: Which version are you running `check_http -V`?

Comment: What version of openssl is involved? Your command works on my nagios-plugins 1.4.13 with 0.9.8e-7.el5.

Answer (score 2):

The `-H` option to `check_http` and ssl based virtual hosts don't interact well. Try using `-I` rather than `-H`. ( You can use a dns name with the `-I` option. )